# Setting up emacs with openCL

Tags: emacs, binding, linker, opencl

What steps are needed to get a simple OpenCL enabled program to compile and run using emacs? We're developing with the C++ bindings right now and I have never used emacs but my teammate is very fond of it.

I just need to know how to set up the linker with ATI Stream SDK and basic OpenCL C++ bindings. The actual coding is not the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCL doesn't change anything about the C/C++ project, you can use any build system you would otherwise use (vanilla Makefiles, autotools, cmake, etc).

For .cl files I have this in my .emacs:

`(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\.cl$" . c-mode) auto-mode-alist))`

...which forces Emacs to treat them as C files.

> I just need to know how to set up the linker with ATI Stream SDK and basic OpenCL C++ bindings.

You need to `#include <CL/cl.hpp>` and to  pass `-lOpenCL` to the linker, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Care trying to make this more precise? OpenCL programs (kernels) are usually compiled using the API calls from a program written in C or C++. Running the program, as well as transferring data back and forth to the memory of the host program, are likewise handled through the API.

Comment: I just mean setting up the linker and everything, not the actual coding. I should have mentioned we're using ATI Stream so i'll put that in question